# Is there a way to improve performance of procedural materials in the viewport without affecting render quality?

Tags: materials, procedural

Most of my materials are procedural, but they are taxing my viewport performance?

Is there a way to limit their effect in the view port when using viewport shading, like you can limit the texture limit using the *Simplify* to improve performance without affecting final render quality?

I could disable the problematic nodes manually but its not ideal, because I would need to toggle them again every time when rendering and when in viewport shading.

I could set a driver in a node before the output node to change to a simple mat for all of them although that could be problematic for all linked mats, I would need to again do it manually for all different linked blend files.

Is there another way to do it, or is there an addon that addresses this issue?

Comment: If you need to enable and disable many specific nodes at once, and you don't want to do it manually, then you should be able to create appropriate scripts using ChatGPT. Personally, I use this type of script to enable and disable "Denoise" nodes in the composer.

Comment: @Zyzio i could do that using drivers and make it like be a simplified version of the node and change them all at once, i could use the script to make it change automaticaly. but i dont see that working on linked objects where you cant at all interact with their shader nodes. unless i guess if i could have a script that would change the nodes located in other blend files to affect the linked objects shaders. IDK how to do it tho i ll try it somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Material Output* nodes support specifying different render engines.

You can have multiple *Material Output* per material tree, each targetting a different render engine, this effectively allows you to set up to different node trees for visualization and rendering purposes.

Since viewport preview is usually achieved through EEVEE and final render may use Cycles, you can have two *Material Output* nodes each targetting its own render engine, and sharing only parts of the node tree, such that the computationally heavier output (bigger textures, complex nodes, heavy shaders) is used only for Cycles (final render), for example, while a partial or simplified version of it is used by EEVEE (thus for viewport preview purposes).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, thats exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much good sir